# add a string to every row of a column in listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

i make a listview and bind it to a CollectionViewSource
`<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" Name="Flistview" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="FIdcolumn" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Fpricecolumn" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price}" Header="price"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>`
its like this:
`Id       pirce
 1        100
 2        200
 3        300`
how can i append a string in every row of column price?
i want be like this
`Id       pirce
 1        100 $
 2        200 $
 3        300 $`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="Fpricecolumn" 
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price, StringFormat={}{0}$}" Header="price"/>
```

Comment: very appreciate